# Classification report changes with each run

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix

I use the code below to get the `confusion matrix` and the `classification report` of the classification model, but the result changes with each run! Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

bankdata = pd.read_csv("bill_authentication.csv")

X = bankdata.drop('Class', axis=1)
y = bankdata['Class']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)

svclassifier = SVC(kernel='rbf')
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

Comment: Can you specify "run"? Do you re-train with every run as well?

Comment: @gtancev Yes, I train with each run. I want to know what exactly is the classification accuracy to compare it with other models.

Comment: Not possible to help you unless you show a [reprex]

Comment: Please check the edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `random_states` for `train_test_split`. Without setting it each run gets a different random state. Resulting in different train test splits. Thus resulting in different input for your classifier which can (and in your case is) resulting in differences in outcome.

So for example if you set random_state to a fixed value, you will get the same results between runs so change to this line of code. The precise value you set `random_state` to does not matter aslong as it is the same between runs.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)
```

You can also set random_state for `SVC` but that only plays a part if the `probability` argument is set to `True`. Which by default is set to `False`, so it should not influence your case.

Comment: Now the results are fixed, thanks. But in many previous experiments, I reached 100%. Is there any way to find an optimum random state?

Comment: random_state is not a suitable hyper parameter to tune. [see this question at crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263999/is-random-state-a-parameter-to-tune). But if you really want to, you could run the train test split/training of your classifier in a for loop  with a range of random_state values and then choose one that results with 100% accuracy.